# pass byte[] array parameter to wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, arrays

I Use MVC 4 and WCF service.

**Here's my viewmodel where i call the service.**

```
The objSwatchClass has a property byte[] of an image.
int updatedSeqNo = objSwatchService.InsertSwatch(objSwatchClass);
```

**Binding in my application's web.config**

```
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>

</binding>
```

[image: Error when i call the service with byte as parameter]
[image: Detailed Error]

Comment: objSwatchClass has a property SwatchImage that you can see in the image. SwatchImage = imgArray. Its passed. I want to pass whole object with byte[] as a property of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have not published your full binding, but according the error it seems your client binding uses MTOM while your serevr binding does not (plain text). Make sure they are in sync to either setting depending on your needs (MTOM is more optimized).